# Tool/way to preserve handset layout proportions on tablet devices

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's an example layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

On a handset(480x800) and a tablet(1280x800) the layout has different amount of space left from the imageview to the bottom. The image isn't scaled on the tablet and dp values result in relatively same physical values.

Is there a way/tool to save handset proportions for tablets so that images, spaces(dp) get scaled? I  guess, I could use values-xlarge/dimen.xml, values-720dp/dimen.xml, but it's a lot of mechanical job to. Any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
      :
      :        
 android:focusable="true"
      :
/>
```

Comment: also this might work  <supports-screens android:resizeable="true" />

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust scaling of ImageView 
add

```
 android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Here are the ImageView Scale types 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: no, I have another application that is being tested on a nexus 4 and it looks not quite good. It's probably because it falls into the "large" bucket.

Comment: Yeah, when you put images let say "100x100" in drawable_mdpi it will be scaled directly when your using a device that has a large screen.
The best way is to put the similar imagename to different drawable folders. For Example you put A.png (100 x 100) in drawable_mdpi and another A.png (200 x 200) in drawable_hdpi ... and so on 
Those folders are categorize in pixel densities with respect to the device the app is running.

Comment: the thing is - it doesn't get scaled between buckets, for instance normal and large, however it does scale within the same bucket(ldpi-xhdpi). I dont want to put any other files - I just want it to save propotions.

Comment: you can try using BitmapFactory and resize the image programatically depending proportion to the dimensions of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your app to be 2 times bigger (all dimentions and font sizes x2) on 2 times larger dispay you can manually change display density (reduce it in a half). Android wont mind and will work as usual. I use this trik when I want my app to be the same and only change scale depending on screen size. Read about [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html)/[DisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)/[updateConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#updateConfiguration%28android.content.res.Configuration,%20android.util.DisplayMetrics%29). Here is draft code you should run in activity's onCreate. I give you exact code later.

```
DisplayMetrics dm = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
// fix display density here to scale all activity's dimentions
context.getResources().updateConfiguration(null, dm);
```

But it isn't proper android way. You should provide different resources for different screen sizes using appropriate resourse folders.

Comment: providing different resources like values/dimen.xml is a hell lot of work - I've already done it on other project but I dont think it has to be that painful. Looking for another solution at least in terms of dp/sp scaling

Comment: that is why I told you about the trik: manually fix display density before statring activity. All dimentions will be scaled automatically.

Comment: I dont have it right now, I'll share it later today or tomorrow )